# Where do I specify the resolver for an interface type in Apollo server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

If I have the interface in my typeDefs of:

```
interface EntityBase @key(fields: "id") {
    ${commonEntProps}
}
```

Then I also need a resolveType in my resolvers like so:

```
EntityBase: {
    __resolveType(entBase, context, info) {
        if (entBase.name) {
            return 'Entity';
        }

        if (entBase.email) {
            return 'User';
        }

        return null;
    }
},
```

This I understand, but what I do not understand is where or how I declare the resolvers for the types returned by __resolverType. I do not mean the properties of Entity or User, I mean the types Entity and User themselves, both of them are already defined in the resolvers object with mappings for their properties.

How do I tell the server which method to execute to return an Entity or a User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you don't.

Unions and interfaces are abstract types that GraphQL resolves *at runtime* into concrete object types (in this case an `Entity` or a `User`). If you have some field that returns a List of `EntityBases`, you will fetch the data from your database or other data source to get those objects. GraphQL will then use the provided `resolveType` function to determine the type of each object in the list. The object's type, combined with the actual query, then determines the shape of the response.

You can't use the object's type to determine a method to fetch the object, because it's type is determined by the fetched data.